# Custom error bar for each datapoint Office 365 Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, office365

I have a dataset where each point has a different sized error bar. With Excel on Office 365, how can I customise the size of an error bar of an individual point? On the "Vertical Error Bar" menu for the series there is only "Fixed Value", "Percentage" and "Standard Deviation/Error" but not "Custom" for example.

EDIT :

Image of the chart [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVLIh.jpg), no "Chart Elements" plus sign. The options for the error bars are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY2ju.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the errors in the table with the data, create you chart and insert Error bars, choosing "More Options" from the menu

[image]

At the bottom of the Error Bar Options, choose "Custom" for the Error Amount

[image]

And click on Specify Value

In the dialog box, select the ranges for the positive and negative error values

[image]

Sample chart:

[image]

Comment: I don't have the Chart Elements menu, there is no plus symbol on the left of my chart, and inside the series menu after double clicking the chart there is no custom option.

Comment: What type of chart do you have? Maybe edit your question to include some screencaps (you can upload them to http://imgur.com and someone with enough reputation will embed them for you

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: I had the same problem. For me, the solution was to install the local MS 365 App instead of using the web browser version.
Once I installed MS Office 365 locally on my PC, it worked as described above by @cybernetic.nomad .